# How to remove block and block arguments in other XML layout magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="Vendor_Extension::order/items/renderer/default.phtml" name="custom_order_view_renderer"/>
             <action method="setChild">
                   <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                   <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">custom_order_view_renderer</argument>
             </action>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use it by adding null type.

```
<argument name="alias" xsi:type="null" />
<argument name="block" xsi:type="null" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but we need to remove block and block arguments in other XML layout file

Comment: Okay No problem , I am just sharing the approach so you can remove any block using <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>  and remove arguments using <argument name="argument_name" xsi:type="null" />  in any layout.

Comment: that way tried and i getting error like...https://i.imgur.com/iNonA75.png

Comment: And i don't think so Magento is allowed to remove blocks in another layout, we need to override or extend the same layout other than Magento unable to identify the block of the other layout. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any block with id=custom_order_view_renderer ?

Comment: NO, I  have used above code

Comment: first try with some existing block id, if  custom_order_view_renderer block not exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150284/discussion-between-keval-chauhan-and-harish-kuril).